# When I try to compile my code using makefile, it shows 'ilcplex/ilocplex.h' file not found

Tags: c++

When I try to use the cplex from IBM in my code and try to compile it, it shows the following error. I've provided the path to the cplex include file and the concert include file, but it still says 'ilcplex/ilocplex.h' file not found.

```
test: test.o assembly.pb.o Mesh.o Assembly.o Part.o Mate.o MateConnector.o ConstraintsMath.o ConnectGraph.o Model.o myOptimizer.o
    g++ test.o assembly.pb.o Mesh.o Assembly.o Part.o Mate.o MateConnector.o ConnectGraph.o ConstraintsMath.o Model.o myOptimizer.o -o test -lprotobuf
test.o: test.cc assembly.pb.h Assembly.h Mate.h Model.h Mesh.h Part.h MateConnector.h ConnectGraph.h ConstraintsMath.h myOptimizer.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c test.cc
Mesh.o: Mesh.cc Mesh.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c Mesh.cc
Assembly.o: Assembly.cc Assembly.h Mate.h Model.h Mesh.h MateConnector.h ConnectGraph.h myOptimizer.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c Assembly.cc
Part.o: Part.cc Part.h Model.h Mesh.h MateConnector.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c Part.cc
Mate.o: Mate.cc Mate.h Model.h Mesh.h MateConnector.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c Mate.cc
assembly.pb.o: assembly.pb.cc assembly.pb.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c assembly.pb.cc
MateConnector.o: MateConnector.cc MateConnector.h ConstraintsMath.h Model.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c MateConnector.cc
ConstraintsMath.o: ConstraintsMath.cc ConstraintsMath.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c ConstraintsMath.cc
ConnectGraph.o: ConnectGraph.cc ConnectGraph.h Part.h MateConnector.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c ConnectGraph.cc
Model.o: Model.cc Model.h Mesh.h Mate.h
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c Model.cc
myOptimizer.o: myOptimizer.cc myOptimizer.h
    g++ -DIL_STD -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/concert/include \
     -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c myOptimizer.cc \
     -L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/concert/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic\
     -L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic \
     -lcplex
clean:
    rm -rf test *.o *~ *.dSYM
```

The error it showed is:

```
c++    -c -o myOptimizer.o myOptimizer.cc
myOptimizer.cc:4:10: fatal error: 'ilcplex/ilocplex.h' file not found
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [myOptimizer.o] Error 1
```

Comment: The build rule in the makefile doesn't seem to be the command that causes the error. Can you paste the whole makefile?

Comment: What is the full path to ilcplex/ilocplex.h?

Comment: Just pasted the whole makefile. The full path is /Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include/ilcplex/ilocplex.h which I've added to the -I flag.

Comment: `c++  -c -o .... ` - something clearly is running `c++` instead of `g++`, so it's not your rule, not your makefile.

Comment: But why this happens? Since besides this line, all the other lines in the makefile run correctly, which are using the code in my makefile instead of others.

Comment: It looks like make is executing some default rule. Are you sure make is actually using the makefile you provided? Can you try to run with `make -f XXX myOptimizer.o` where XXX is replaced by the absolute path to your makefile.

Comment: By using this ```make -f XXX myOptimizer.o```, it still gives this error and it seems is still using some default role: ```D-10-19-210-160:meshreconstruction chenduowen$ make -f /Users/chenduowen/Desktop/meshreconstruction/Makefile myOptimizer.o
c++    -c -o myOptimizer.o myOptimizer.cc
myOptimizer.cc:4:10: fatal error: 'ilcplex/ilocplex.h' file not found
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [myOptimizer.o] Error 1```

Comment: Very weird. You could try option `-d`. That gives more details about what make is doing. Maybe that sheds some light? Could it be that there is some typo in your makefile? Also, the offending rule is the only one that spans multiple lines, do things work better if you put everything onto a single line?

I tried you makefile here and it works fine.